# DDD, контексты и карта контекстов

Tags: архитектура, проектирование, ddd

Всем доброго времени суток.
Нужна ваша помощь в использовании методологии DDD.

Допустим у меня есть система проверки качества оборудования (абстрактный пример). У меня есть 2 контекста:

- Контекст добавляемого в систему оборудования
- Контекст проверки добавленного оборудования.

При этом каждому типу оборудования, определенному в контексте добавляемого оборудования соответствуют свои подключаемые модули проверки, определенные в контексте проверки добавленного оборудования.

Вопрос № 1 - Если для предприятия главным являются методы диагностики оборудования, то, по идее, смысловым ядром является Контекст проверки добавленного оборудования. Так ли это? При этом стоит учитывать, что добавление нового оборудования в систему осуществляется в контексте добавляемого в систему оборудования.

Вопрос № 2 - могут ли оба контекста обращаться к единой базе данных? Так сложилось, что база уже сформирована до момента разработки системы проверки оборудования. Как я думаю, в Контексте добавляемого в систему оборудования происходит обращение к репозиторию с последующей записи в базу нового оборудования. В Контексте проверки добавленного оборудования происходит обращение к базе для получения нужной в текущем контексте информации об оборудовании с последующей его проверкой.

Вопрос № 3 - В каких отношениях между собой состоят оба контекста (например, Общее ядро, Заказчик-поставщик и т. д.)?